# How much performance is left on the table?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

I'm reading a paper and I don't understand what's the meaning of the following sentence:

> It is unclear **how much performance is left on the table** given the extra layers of abstraction and indirection in the contract library.

So which one does it mean?

1. the performance is good, so we cannot further improve the performance.
2. we cannot further improve the performance.

for the entire paragraph:

[image: pic for the sentence quoted]

Comment: "To leave something on the table" is an expression related to deal-making and a sub-optimal result. As such, the extra layers of abstraction and indirection lead to a degradation of the performance.

Comment: @kaipmdh: thank you!